# "R" is not regestering as Equal to "R" when send over TCP connection

Tags: c#, string, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am trying to have a client send a command to my service, that command being "R".
But when I try to make an IF statement it will not register the "R" that came in via TCP as being equal to a string R that I have made in my program. Here is some of my code.

```
    byte[] message = new byte[1024];
        byte[] command = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("R");
        stream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
        string messageIn = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message);
        //updateUI("New Message =  " + messageIn);
        string commandString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(command);

         if (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message) == Encoding.ASCII.GetString(command))
```

As you can see, I was of the impression that taking "R" into bytes and then out of bytes would have caused this problem hence the giant if statement. However not a single one of these conditions returns true as my if block  never runs.

I know that it is returning "R" because when I output it to a textbox, that is what gets printed. Is the very act of transfering it VIA tcp changing the string somehow?

Comment: This code really makes no sense at all. How would it ever be possible that e.g. `message == command`? The fact that this is a reference comparison and thus guaranteed to be false no matter what you try notwithstanding, those two arrays don't even have the same contents! Are you just randomly spamming comparisons? Please take out all the senseless parts of the code and leave only what is relevant to your question (which you also need to clearly state).

Comment: Use the debugger to see what's in your `message` array after the call to `stream.Read()`

Comment: I am getting a string  "R" that was encoded into a byte[] and sent over stream. That byte[] is message. I want to check if that byte[] converted back into a string with Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message) is equal to "R".

Comment: Just checked the debugger, byte [0] is 82 and the rest of the bytes are 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from the vast number of pointless comparisons you're making, the first problem is that you're ignoring the result of `Stream.Read`... and instead creating a string out of the whole 1024 bytes within `message`. If you change it to:

```
int bytesRead = stream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
string messageIn = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
```

... then you'd be in a much better position. However, that's probably *still* not good enough, unless that's *all* that's going to be sent. You're dealing with a stream, but I suspect you're *thinking* about it as if it's message-oriented - as if a single `Write` on one end of the connection will map to a single `Read` on the other end. That's not how stream-oriented protocols work. If you have a logical "message" then when reading from the stream you might end up with part of a message, multiple messages, anything. Common ways of fixing this are:

- Include a length prefix before each message
- Use a separator (e.g. a line break for text-based protocols)

See [Marc Gravell's blog post on this](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html) for more details.

Additionally, if your protocol *is* text-based, it would be a good idea to create a `StreamReader` around the stream so that you can just read text (e.g. a line at a time) instead of converting all over the place.

Comment: that works a whole lot better, thank you! I don't know if you are the same guy but I'm pretty sure I have watched a video series by you on pluralsight.

Comment: @BurntCandy: If it's someone with my name, then yes, that's me :)